# Redirect the output of a program with a segfault

Tags: c, bash, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to debug a segfault in my C program. I added a few `printf()`, but it generates a lot of text, so I tried to redirect the output:

```
./a.out > log
```

It didn't work, it printed  `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in the terminal and didn't print anything to the log file.

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Turn off output buffering or call `fflush(stdout)` after each printf. The program is crashing before the last few printfs get flushed to the file.

Comment: Or write these debugging messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. It's line-buffered.

Comment: Or use a debugger. It will tell you instantly the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault.

Comment: @Barmar Thx, adding ```fflush(stdout)``` worked

Comment: Wouldn't analyzing dumped core file with gdb easier than debugging with printfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fflush(stdout)` will force output to be written.

The much more powerful approach is to ensure your program is compiled with debugging information (`gcc -g3`) then use a debugger `gdb ./a.out core`.  `bt` will now tell you were your program crashed.

You can often use `strace`, `ltrace`, eBPF (Linux) or similar tracing utilities to learn something useful.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know `ltrace` existed, it really helped me